# Free Pascal: which component for highlighting part of item/string

Tags: components, freepascal

Which component (TListView, TStringGrid, ...) do you recommend for this:

- presentation of list items
- items will be strings
- specified substrings (e.g. words) will be highlighted - I need to highlight some words in a string/item.

I am not aware of a way to change background color for a **part** of string (using OnCustomDrawItem).

Comment: Maybe SynEdit... it's more for code syntax highlighting but perhaps it is flexible enough to accomodate your needs.